# converting a string like 'AlmodCookies' into an int

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I want to convert the column to binary to fit it in my ML model and the problem is that I get the results as booleans. when I try to convert the data into integers I get error messages. All what I marked as a comment out (except the last comment) in my code is me trying to convert the data into an integer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('food_ingredients_and_allergens-checkpoint.csv')
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
data['Food Product'] = data['Food Product'].str.replace(" ", "")
#data['Food Product'] = data['Food Product'].astype('int')
#data['Food Product'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Food Product'], errors='coerce').astype('float')
data = data.join(pd.get_dummies(data['Food Product']))
#data['Food Product'] = data['Food Product'].astype('int').astype('float')
print (data['Food Product'].dtype)
#print(int(float(data['Food Product'])))
#data = data.drop('Food Product', axis=1)

print(data)
```

Here you can find the column I'm talking about

```
    Food Product
1   Almond Cookies
2   Almond Cookies
3   Chicken Noodle Soup
4   Chicken Noodle Soup
5   Cheddar Cheese
6   Ranch Dressing
7   Caramel Popcorn
8   Caesar Salad
9   Caesar Wrap
10  Strawberry Smoothie
11  Cheese Pizza
12  Margherita Pizza
13  Mashed Potatoes
14  Greek Yogurt
15  Caesar Salad Wrap
16  Caprese Salad
17  Berry Smoothie
18  Caesar Salad
19  Berry Parfait
20  Chicken Alfredo
21  Pesto Pizza
22  Beef Stroganoff
23  Banana Smoothie
24  Watermelon Salad
25  Chicken Parmesan
26  Mango Lassi
27  Greek Salad
28  Butternut Squash Soup
29  Margherita Pasta
30  Greek Gyro Wrap
31  Spinach and Feta Stuffed Chicken
32  Chicken Fettuccine Alfredo
33  Caprese Sandwich
34  Mushroom Risotto
35  Greek Yogurt Parfait
36  Eggplant Parmesan
37  Banana Pudding
38  Margherita Pizza
39  Chicken Caesar Wrap
40  Greek Spanakopita
41  Mushroom Soup
42  Greek Yogurt
43  Spinach Artichoke Dip
44  Chocolate Mousse
45  Stuffed Portobello Mushrooms
46  Caprese Salad
47  Tandoori Chicken
48  Beef Stroganoff
49  Strawberry Smoothie
50  Baked Garlic Parmesan Chicken
51  Mushroom and Goat Cheese Flatbread
52  Margherita Pasta
53  Pumpkin Soup
54  Butternut Squash Soup
55  Caprese Skewers
56  Chicken Piccata
57  Berry Parfait
58  Stuffed Mushrooms
59  Spinach Artichoke Dip
60  Chocolate Mousse
61  Stuffed Portobello Mushrooms
62  Caprese Salad
63  Tandoori Chicken
64  Beef Stroganoff
65  Strawberry Smoothie
66  Baked Garlic Parmesan Chicken
67  Butter Chicken
68  Palak Paneer
69  Tandoori Chicken
70  Rogan Josh
71  Paneer Tikka
72  Dal Makhani
73  Malai Kofta
74  Chicken Tikka Masala
75  Gulab Jamun
76  Chicken Korma
77  Malai Chicken Tikka
78  Dahi Vada
79  Chicken Malai Tikka`your text`
80  Matar Paneer
81  Rasgulla
82  Rabri
83  Chicken Korma
84  Gulab Jamun
85  Rogan Josh
86  Kheer
87  Rasmalai
88  Chicken Caesar Salad
89  Chocolate Mousse
90  Quiche Lorraine
91  Chicken Piccata
92  Chicken Tikka Masala
93  Sweet Potato Casserole
94  Baked Brie
95  French Onion Soup
96  Greek Gyro
97  French Onion Soup
98  Omelette
99  Egg Salad
100 Egg Salad
101 Quiche
102 Egg Salad Sandwich
103 Egg Fried Rice
104 Fish Sticks
105 Fish Sticks
106 Baked Salmon
107 Teriyaki Salmon
108 Baked Salmon
109 Lemon Dill Salmon
110 Baked Salmon
111 Malabar Fish Curry
112 Baked Cod
113 Baked Cod
114 Tuna Sandwich
115 Tuna Salad
116 Sushi
117 Teriyaki Salmon
118 Sushi Bowl
119 Honey Soy Glazed Salmon
120 Sushi Bowl
121 Honey Soy Glazed Salmon
122 Milk Chocolate
123 Milk Chocolate
124 Vanilla Ice Cream
125 Vanilla Yogurt
126 Strawberry Yogurt
127 Strawberry Yogurt
128 Tomato Soup
129 Apple
130 Tomato Soup
131 Apple
132 Orange Juice
133 Greek Salad
134 Spaghetti Bolognese
135 Honey Mustard Chicken
136 BBQ Ribs
137 Quinoa Salad
138 Vegetable Stir-Fry
139 Beef Burger
140 French Fries
141 Lemonade
142 Gazpacho
143 Beef Tacos
144 Lentil Soup
145 Chicken Curry
146 Ratatouille
147 Pesto Pasta
148 Chicken Stir-Fry
149 Veggie Burger
150 Vegetable Soup
151 Spinach Salad
152 Chicken Enchiladas
153 Minestrone Soup
154 Salsa
155 Lemon Garlic Chicken
156 Pancetta Pasta
157 Chicken Teriyaki
158 Spinach Stuffed Chicken
159 Coconut Curry
160 Apple Cider
161 Ratatouille
162 Avocado Toast
163 Beef Stir-Fry
164 Black Bean Soup
165 Beef Tacos
166 Cucumber Salad
167 Fruit Salad
168 Sausage Pizza
169 Chicken Fajitas
170 Mango Salsa
171 Lentil Curry
172 Green Smoothie
173 Stuffed Bell Peppers
174 Beef and Broccoli
175 Cabbage Rolls
176 Caramel Apple
177 Sweet Potato Fries
178 Beef Chili
179 Pesto Chicken
180 Beef Burritos
181 Chicken Shawarma
182 Stuffed Mushrooms
183 Zucchini Noodles
184 Sweet and Sour Chicken
185 Beef Kabobs
186 Tomato Bruschetta
187 Quinoa Stuffed Peppers
188 Veggie Omelette
189 Ratatouille
190 Beef Tacos
191 Quinoa Salad
192 Vegetable Stir-Fry
193 Buffalo Wings
194 Lentil Soup
195 Stuffed Cabbage Rolls
196 Orange Chicken
197 Honey Mustard Chicken
198 Lentil Salad
199 Cilantro Lime Chicken
200 Ratatouille Pizza
201 Chicken Curry
202 Pesto Pasta Salad
203 Beef and Mushroom Stir-Fry
204 Tofu Curry
205 Stuffed Bell Peppers
206 Stuffed Bell Peppers
207 Greek Moussaka
208 Brussels Sprouts
209 Baked Chicken Wings
210 Mango Coconut Popsicles
211 Ratatouille Pasta
212 Chicken Noodle Soup
213 Mango Salsa
214 Spinach Salad
215 Caramelized Onions
216 Beef Stir-Fry
217 Strawberry Spinach Salad
218 Ratatouille Tart
219 Honey Glazed Carrots
220 Cucumber Salad
221 Greek Lemon Potatoes
222 Stuffed Tomatoes
223 Avocado Toast
224 Lemon Pepper Chicken
225 Chicken Shawarma
226 Lemon Herb Roasted Chicken
227 Greek Lemon Chicken
228 Roasted Brussels Sprouts
229 Beef Burritos
230 Raspberry Spinach Salad
231 Chicken and Rice Soup
232 Chicken Fajitas
233 Vegetable Curry
234 Ratatouille
235 Pesto Pasta Salad
236 Beef and Mushroom Stir-Fry
237 Tofu Curry
238 Stuffed Bell Peppers
239 Greek Moussaka
240 Brussels Sprouts
241 Baked Chicken Wings
242 Mango Coconut Popsicles
243 Ratatouille Pasta
244 Chicken Noodle Soup
245 Mango Salsa
246 Spinach Salad
247 Caramelized Onions
248 Beef Stir-Fry
249 Strawberry Spinach Salad
250 Ratatouille Tart
251 Honey Glazed Carrots
252 Cucumber Salad
253 Greek Lemon Potatoes
254 Stuffed Tomatoes
255 Biryani
256 Chole Bhature
257 Masala Dosa
258 Samosa
259 Aloo Gobi
260 Chicken Biryani
261 Vada Pav
262 Pani Puri
263 Rajma Chawal
264 Chicken Curry
265 Vegetable Biryani
266 Chana Masala
267 Paniyaram
268 Chicken Biryani
269 Pav Bhaji
270 Hyderabadi Biryani
271 Chicken Curry
272 Dosa
273 Chole Kulche
274 Gobi Manchurian
275 Mutton Biryani
276 Oatmeal
277 Chicken Satay
278 Peanut Butter
279 Peanut Butter
280 Chicken Satay
281 Chicken Satay
282 Pesto Chicken
283 Zucchini Noodles with Pesto
284 Pesto Chicken
285 Rice Pudding
286 Shrimp Scampi
287 Shrimp Scampi Pasta
288 Garlic Shrimp
289 Lemon Garlic Shrimp
290 Lemon Garlic Shrimp
291 Prawn Biryani
292 Lobster Bisque
293 Caesar Shrimp Skewers
294 Shrimp Scampi
295 Lobster Bisque
296 Caesar Shrimp Skewers
297 Prawn Curry
298 Lobster Roll
299 Lobster Roll
300 Bacon-Wrapped Shrimp
301 Shrimp Fried Rice
302 Soy Milk
303 Soy Milk
304 Tofu Stir-Fry
305 Miso Soup
306 Tofu Scramble
307 Chicken Teriyaki
308 Tofu Stir-Fry
309 Teriyaki Beef
310 Sushi Rolls
311 Wheat Bread
312 Wheat Bread
313 Zucchini Bread
314 Chicken Noodle Casserole
315 Onion Rings
316 Chicken Pot Pie
317 Grilled Portobello Mushroom Burger
318 Aloo Paratha
319 Oatmeal Raisin Cookies
320 Oatmeal Raisin Cookies
321 Pancakes
322 Carrot Cake
323 Blueberry Muffins
324 Chocolate Chip Cookies
325 Mushroom Risotto
326 Cinnamon Rolls
327 Pineapple Upside-Down Cake
328 Apple Pie
329 Banana Bread
330 Vanilla Cupcakes
331 Apple Crisp
332 Pasta Carbonara
333 Blueberry Pancakes
334 Lemon Bars
335 Pumpkin Pie
336 Mixed Berry Pie
337 Garlic Bread
338 Berry Cobbler
339 Baked Ziti
340 Baked Ziti
341 Key Lime Pie
342 Lemon Poppy Seed Muffins
343 Chicken Quesadilla
344 Pancake Stack
345 Strawberry Shortcake
346 Berry Crumble
347 Raspberry Cheesecake
348 Blueberry Pancakes
349 Oatmeal Raisin Cookies
350 Apple Crisp
351 Chicken Enchiladas
352 Caesar Salad Wrap
353 Caesar Salad Wrap
354 S'mores
355 Tiramisu
356 Cinnamon Rolls
357 Chicken Caesar Salad
358 Vegetable Lasagna
359 Garlic Bread
360 Chicken Alfredo Pizza
361 Caesar Pasta Salad
362 Baked Apple
363 Apple Pie
364 Chicken Parmesan
365 Pumpkin Pie
366 Blueberry Muffins
367 Sausage and Pepper Pizza
368 Beef Wellington
369 Baked Ziti
370 Lemon Poppy Seed Muffins
371 Apple Crisp
372 Chicken Enchiladas
373 Caesar Salad Wrap
374 S'mores
375 Tiramisu
376 Cinnamon Rolls
377 Chicken Caesar Salad
378 Vegetable Lasagna
379 Garlic Bread
380 Chicken Alfredo Pizza
381 Caesar Pasta Salad
382 Baked Apple
383 Apple Pie
384 Chicken Parmesan
385 Pumpkin Pie
386 Blueberry Muffins
387 Sausage and Pepper Pizza
388 Beef Wellington
389 Jalebi
390 Butter Naan
391 Tiramisu
392 Chocolate Cake
393 Chocolate Chip Pancakes
394 Lemon Bars
395 Lemon Bars
396 Pecan Pie
397 Zucchini Bread
398 Banana Bread
399 Hawaiian Pizza
```

#data['Food Product'] = data['Food Product'].astype('int').astype('float')
I also tried `astype('float')`**and than ** `astype('int')`**but it didn't work**

Answer (score 1):

you needn't convert "Food Product" column type to int or float.
One Hot Encoding is a method for dealing with categorical data, so you shouldn't convert "Food Product" column to int or float type and then convert it to binary. [Link](https://www.educative.io/blog/one-hot-encoding)

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("food_ingredients_and_allergens.csv")
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["Food Product"])
df
```

result:

|  | Main Ingredient | Sweetener | Fat/Oil | Seasoning | Allergens | Prediction | Food Product_Almond Cookies | Food Product_Aloo Gobi | Food Product_Aloo Paratha | Food Product_Apple | Food Product_Apple Cider | Food Product_Apple Crisp | Food Product_Apple Pie | Food Product_Avocado Toast | Food Product_BBQ Ribs | Food Product_Bacon-Wrapped Shrimp | Food Product_Baked Apple | Food Product_Baked Brie | Food Product_Baked Chicken Wings | Food Product_Baked Cod | Food Product_Baked Garlic Parmesan Chicken | Food Product_Baked Salmon | Food Product_Baked Ziti | Food Product_Banana Bread | Food Product_Banana Pudding | Food Product_Banana Smoothie | Food Product_Beef Burger | Food Product_Beef Burritos | Food Product_Beef Chili | Food Product_Beef Kabobs | Food Product_Beef Stir-Fry | Food Product_Beef Stroganoff | Food Product_Beef Tacos | Food Product_Beef Wellington | Food Product_Beef and Broccoli | Food Product_Beef and Mushroom Stir-Fry | Food Product_Berry Cobbler | Food Product_Berry Crumble | Food Product_Berry Parfait | Food Product_Berry Smoothie | Food Product_Biryani | Food Product_Black Bean Soup | Food Product_Blueberry Muffins | Food Product_Blueberry Pancakes | Food Product_Brussels Sprouts | Food Product_Buffalo Wings | Food Product_Butter Chicken | Food Product_Butter Naan | Food Product_Butternut Squash Soup | Food Product_Cabbage Rolls | Food Product_Caesar Pasta Salad | Food Product_Caesar Salad | Food Product_Caesar Salad Wrap | Food Product_Caesar Shrimp Skewers | Food Product_Caesar Wrap | Food Product_Caprese Salad | Food Product_Caprese Sandwich | Food Product_Caprese Skewers | Food Product_Caramel Apple | Food Product_Caramel Popcorn | Food Product_Caramelized Onions | Food Product_Carrot Cake | Food Product_Chana Masala | Food Product_Cheddar Cheese | Food Product_Cheese Pizza | Food Product_Chicken Alfredo | Food Product_Chicken Alfredo Pizza | Food Product_Chicken Biryani | Food Product_Chicken Caesar Salad | Food Product_Chicken Caesar Wrap | Food Product_Chicken Curry | Food Product_Chicken Enchiladas | Food Product_Chicken Fajitas | Food Product_Chicken Fettuccine Alfredo | Food Product_Chicken Korma | Food Product_Chicken Malai Tikka | Food Product_Chicken Noodle Casserole | Food Product_Chicken Noodle Soup | Food Product_Chicken Parmesan | Food Product_Chicken Piccata | Food Product_Chicken Pot Pie | Food Product_Chicken Quesadilla | Food Product_Chicken Satay | Food Product_Chicken Shawarma | Food Product_Chicken Stir-Fry | Food Product_Chicken Teriyaki | Food Product_Chicken Tikka Masala | Food Product_Chicken and Rice Soup | Food Product_Chocolate Cake | Food Product_Chocolate Chip Cookies | Food Product_Chocolate Chip Pancakes | Food Product_Chocolate Mousse | Food Product_Chole Bhature | Food Product_Chole Kulche | Food Product_Cilantro Lime Chicken | Food Product_Cinnamon Rolls | Food Product_Coconut Curry | Food Product_Cucumber Salad | Food Product_Dahi Vada | Food Product_Dal Makhani | Food Product_Dosa | Food Product_Egg Fried Rice | Food Product_Egg Salad | Food Product_Egg Salad Sandwich | Food Product_Eggplant Parmesan | Food Product_Fish Sticks | Food Product_French Fries | Food Product_French Onion Soup | Food Product_Fruit Salad | Food Product_Garlic Bread | Food Product_Garlic Shrimp | Food Product_Gazpacho | Food Product_Gobi Manchurian | Food Product_Greek Gyro | Food Product_Greek Gyro Wrap | Food Product_Greek Lemon Chicken | Food Product_Greek Lemon Potatoes | Food Product_Greek Moussaka | Food Product_Greek Salad | Food Product_Greek Spanakopita | Food Product_Greek Yogurt | Food Product_Greek Yogurt Parfait | Food Product_Green Smoothie | Food Product_Grilled Portobello Mushroom Burger | Food Product_Gulab Jamun | Food Product_Hawaiian Pizza | Food Product_Honey Glazed Carrots | Food Product_Honey Mustard Chicken | Food Product_Honey Soy Glazed Salmon | Food Product_Hyderabadi Biryani | Food Product_Jalebi | Food Product_Key Lime Pie | Food Product_Kheer | Food Product_Lemon Bars | Food Product_Lemon Dill Salmon | Food Product_Lemon Garlic Chicken | Food Product_Lemon Garlic Shrimp | Food Product_Lemon Herb Roasted Chicken | Food Product_Lemon Pepper Chicken | Food Product_Lemon Poppy Seed Muffins | Food Product_Lemonade | Food Product_Lentil Curry | Food Product_Lentil Salad | Food Product_Lentil Soup | Food Product_Lobster Bisque | Food Product_Lobster Roll | Food Product_Malabar Fish Curry | Food Product_Malai Chicken Tikka | Food Product_Malai Kofta | Food Product_Mango Coconut Popsicles | Food Product_Mango Lassi | Food Product_Mango Salsa | Food Product_Margherita Pasta | Food Product_Margherita Pizza | Food Product_Masala Dosa | Food Product_Mashed Potatoes | Food Product_Matar Paneer | Food Product_Milk Chocolate | Food Product_Minestrone Soup | Food Product_Miso Soup | Food Product_Mixed Berry Pie | Food Product_Mushroom Risotto | Food Product_Mushroom Soup | Food Product_Mushroom and Goat Cheese Flatbread | Food Product_Mutton Biryani | Food Product_Oatmeal | Food Product_Oatmeal Raisin Cookies | Food Product_Omelette | Food Product_Onion Rings | Food Product_Orange Chicken | Food Product_Orange Juice | Food Product_Palak Paneer | Food Product_Pancake Stack | Food Product_Pancakes | Food Product_Pancetta Pasta | Food Product_Paneer Tikka | Food Product_Pani Puri | Food Product_Paniyaram | Food Product_Pasta Carbonara | Food Product_Pav Bhaji | Food Product_Peanut Butter | Food Product_Pecan Pie | Food Product_Pesto Chicken | Food Product_Pesto Pasta | Food Product_Pesto Pasta Salad | Food Product_Pesto Pizza | Food Product_Pineapple Upside-Down Cake | Food Product_Prawn Biryani | Food Product_Prawn Curry | Food Product_Pumpkin Pie | Food Product_Pumpkin Soup | Food Product_Quiche | Food Product_Quiche Lorraine | Food Product_Quinoa Salad | Food Product_Quinoa Stuffed Peppers | Food Product_Rabri | Food Product_Rajma Chawal | Food Product_Ranch Dressing | Food Product_Rasgulla | Food Product_Rasmalai | Food Product_Raspberry Cheesecake | Food Product_Raspberry Spinach Salad | Food Product_Ratatouille | Food Product_Ratatouille Pasta | Food Product_Ratatouille Pizza | Food Product_Ratatouille Tart | Food Product_Rice Pudding | Food Product_Roasted Brussels Sprouts | Food Product_Rogan Josh | Food Product_S'mores | Food Product_Salsa | Food Product_Samosa | Food Product_Sausage Pizza | Food Product_Sausage and Pepper Pizza | Food Product_Shrimp Fried Rice | Food Product_Shrimp Scampi | Food Product_Shrimp Scampi Pasta | Food Product_Soy Milk | Food Product_Spaghetti Bolognese | Food Product_Spinach Artichoke Dip | Food Product_Spinach Salad | Food Product_Spinach Stuffed Chicken | Food Product_Spinach and Feta Stuffed Chicken | Food Product_Strawberry Shortcake | Food Product_Strawberry Smoothie | Food Product_Strawberry Spinach Salad | Food Product_Strawberry Yogurt | Food Product_Stuffed Bell Peppers | Food Product_Stuffed Cabbage Rolls | Food Product_Stuffed Mushrooms | Food Product_Stuffed Portobello Mushrooms | Food Product_Stuffed Tomatoes | Food Product_Sushi | Food Product_Sushi Bowl | Food Product_Sushi Rolls | Food Product_Sweet Potato Casserole | Food Product_Sweet Potato Fries | Food Product_Sweet and Sour Chicken | Food Product_Tandoori Chicken | Food Product_Teriyaki Beef | Food Product_Teriyaki Salmon | Food Product_Tiramisu | Food Product_Tofu Curry | Food Product_Tofu Scramble | Food Product_Tofu Stir-Fry | Food Product_Tomato Bruschetta | Food Product_Tomato Soup | Food Product_Tuna Salad | Food Product_Tuna Sandwich | Food Product_Vada Pav | Food Product_Vanilla Cupcakes | Food Product_Vanilla Ice Cream | Food Product_Vanilla Yogurt | Food Product_Vegetable Biryani | Food Product_Vegetable Curry | Food Product_Vegetable Lasagna | Food Product_Vegetable Soup | Food Product_Vegetable Stir-Fry | Food Product_Veggie Burger | Food Product_Veggie Omelette | Food Product_Watermelon Salad | Food Product_Wheat Bread | Food Product_Zucchini Bread | Food Product_Zucchini Noodles | Food Product_Zucchini Noodles with Pesto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Almonds | Sugar | Butter | Flour | Almonds, Wheat, Dairy | Contains | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

and also you needn't join the result of the get_dummies function with the original data frame.
this function gives you one hot encoded of your origin data frame

Comment: Why don‘t I need binary values? I Stil get booleans instead of binary and I can‘t use booleans in my ML model. I‘m sorry if I misunderstood something but I’m an absolute beginner in machine learning

Comment: no problem my friend. like you, I am a beginner in machine learning and I am trying to share my knowledge with you. first of all please read this (link) [https://www.educative.io/blog/one-hot-encoding]. because according to your explanation in the question, you want to use the OneHotEncoding method and in general, the basis of this method is to take the categorical values and create multiple columns with the number of them, and then for each row put 1 in the corresponding column and put 0 for other columns.

Comment: I think you confused "BinaryEncoding" with "OneHotEncoding", so I suggest you read this link to fully understand the difference. (link)[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325263/binary-encoding-vs-one-hot-encoding]